# How I can create a angular 1.x "plugin"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well I want create my own `plugin` or `module` for angular 1.5 like `$http`.

**Example: the "angular-own-plugin.js":**

```
angular.module('ownPlugin', function() {
    $scope.functionA = function () {return 1;};
    $scope.functionB = function () {return 2;};
    $scope.functionC = function () {return 3;};
    $scope.functionX = function (n) {return n * $scope.functionA();};
})
```

**Example: "integration" of `$ownPlugin`**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($http, $ownPlugin){
    $scope.number = $ownPlugin.functionX(10);
})
```

Whats is the best way for create plugin? i don't know if using `factory`, `service` or another method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you call it plugin because you want a standalone module to be used wherever you want in your AngularJs apps. So, AngularJs works per modules, therefore the best approach is to use modules.

```
(function () {    
    angular.module('owl', [])
        .factory('$ownPlugin', function() {
            var plugin = {};

            plugin.functionA = function () {return 1;};
            plugin.functionB = function () {return 2;};
            plugin.functionC = function () {return 3;};
            plugin.functionX = function (n) {return n * plugin.functionA();};

            return plugin;
        });    
})();
```

So you can use it on your app by injecting it on the module declaration.

```
(function () {    
    angular.module('myApp', ['owl'])
        .controller('MyCtrl', function ($http, $ownPlugin){
            $scope.number = $ownPlugin.functionX(10);
        });
})();
```

> **NOTE ABOUT USING FACTORY OR SERVICE:** It doesn't make much difference, you may use it for a design decision, factories use the build function as a getter (i.e., `myFactory = MyFactoryFn();`) but a service use the build function as a constructor (i.e., `myService = new MyServiceFn();`)